# MVC FormAction Bootstrap Modal Confirm

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am having difficulties here. I want to create a global Javascript function that prevents a form button submitting until an option is selected on a modal and can be used everywhere in the system. I have a form, here is it simplified:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserCreate", "Administration", FormMethod.Post,
                      new { @Id = "user-form", @Style = "color:#595959;" }))
{
    <input name="submit"
           type="submit"
           class="button"
           id="removeAccount"
           value="Remove account" 
           formaction="@Url.Action("DeleteAccount", "Administration",
                         new { userAuthenticationId = Model.UserAuthentication.Id, 
                               userId = Model.UserId })" 
           formmethod="post"
           onclick="return confirmDialog('Are you sure you wish to remove this account?');"/>

    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" id="save" value="Create user"/>
}
```

There is a submit for the whole form but there is also another button which posts a request to the controller called "RemoveAccount". I want a confirm modal here that prevents the RemoveAccount from submitting. I want it to be global so I can just put a line like this in the `<input>` as there are lots of instances of this in the system. How can I achieve this? With the current code the modal displays but the RemoveAccount submits no matter what you select.

Here is the confirmDialog function:

```
function confirmDialog(message) {

    var fClose = function () {        
        modal.modal("hide");
        return false;
    };

    var onConfirm = function () {
        modal.modal("hide");
        return true;
    };
    
    var modal = $("#confirmModal");
    modal.modal("show");
    $("#confirmMessage").empty().append(message);
    $("#confirmOk").unbind().one('click', onConfirm);
    $("#confirmCancel").unbind().one("click", fClose);
}
```

And the modal html:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="confirmMessage" class="modal-body">
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="confirmOk" type="button" class="button">Ok</button>
                <button id="confirmCancel" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the form is submitting before your confirm javascript has a chance to run.

One solution is to hide the real submit and show the user a fake submit.  When the fake submit is clicked show the modal.  And when the modal is confirmed trigger the click event handler of the real submit button.

To do this change your form to this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserCreate", "Administration", FormMethod.Post,
                      new { @Id = "user-form", @Style = "color:#595959;" }))
{
    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" id="removeAccount"
           value="Remove account"
           formaction="@Url.Action("DeleteAccount", "Administration",
                         new { userAuthenticationId = Model.UserAuthentication.Id,
                               userId = Model.UserId })"
           formmethod="post"
           style="display:none;"
            />

    <button type="button" 
            onclick="return confirmDialog(event,'Are you sure you wish to remove this account?');">
            Remove account
    </button>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" id="save" value="Create user" />
}
```

and your javascript to this

```
 function confirmDialog(event,message) {
    event.preventDefault();       

    var fClose = function () {
        modal.modal("hide");
        return false;
    };

    var onConfirm = function () {
        modal.modal("hide");
        $("#removeAccount").click();  //trigger the click event handler of the real submit
        return true;
    };

    var modal = $("#confirmModal");
    modal.modal("show");
    $("#confirmMessage").empty().append(message);
    $("#confirmOk").unbind().one('click', onConfirm);
    $("#confirmCancel").unbind().one("click", fClose);
}
```

**Edit**
In order to make this method more reusable you could change the fake submit to this

```
<button type="button" 
              onclick="return confirmDialog(event,'#removeAccount','Are you sure you wish to remove this account?');">
       Remove account
</button>
```

i.e. pass the id of the thing you want to submit as a parameter.  Then you would change the javascript to this

```
function confirmDialog(event,submitToConfirm,message) {
    event.preventDefault();       

    var fClose = function () {
        modal.modal("hide");
        return false;
    };

    var onConfirm = function () {
        modal.modal("hide");
        $(submitToConfirm).click();
        return true;
    };

    var modal = $("#confirmModal");
    modal.modal("show");
    $("#confirmMessage").empty().append(message);
    $("#confirmOk").unbind().one('click', onConfirm);
    $("#confirmCancel").unbind().one("click", fClose);
}
```

Comment: That looks like a great solution! Let me try to implement before I mark as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @cullimorer  Were you able to implement?  Any problems?

Comment: Apologies, the project was put on hold but I'm picking it back up today. Will try to implement and get back to you.